# Implementing Cosine similarity loss gives different answer than Tensorflow's

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was implementing cosine similarity loss with my custom python script but it gives me a very different answer than TensorFlow. First see `TensorFlow's` answer:-

```
y_true = [[0., 1.], [1., 1.]]
y_pred = [[0., 1.], [0., 1.]]
loss = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity()
print(loss(y_true, y_pred).numpy())
```

Output:

```
>>> -0.8535534
```

According to the TensorFlow documentation, the formula to compute the loss is this:-

[image]

I implemented the same with plain python as this:-

```
def cosine_similarity(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = -np.sum(np.linalg.norm(y_true) * np.linalg.norm(y_pred))
    return loss

print(cosine_similarity(y_true, y_pred))
```

Output:

```
>>> -2.4494897427831783
```

I don't why I am getting `-2.45` and `TensorFlow` is outputting `-0.85`. Any solution so my answer can match with TensorFlow's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through some documentation,

results from `tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity()`and your function differs for two reasons:

1. As presented in the example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CosineSimilarity),  in `CosineSimiliraty()` function, L2_normalisation is done along **axis=1**

When `np.linalg.norm()` is performed on the whole array because no axis was given. Moreover, the result is summed.

```
y_true = [[0., 1.], [1., 1.]]
y_pred = [[0., 1.], [0., 1.]]

print(tf.math.l2_normalize(y_true,axis=1))

print(np.linalg.norm(y_true))


Outputs
#[[0.         1.        ]
# [0.70710677 0.70710677]]
# 1.7320508075688772 
# Result from np.linalg.norm() is obtained by summing  : 
#[[0.         0.57735026]
#[0.57735026  0.57735026]]
```

2. Secondly I don't know why but considering the example given in the link above,
   Before summing values, `np.mean` is applied along the same axis. They might forget to precise it, in the formula you used.

```
a=tf.math.l2_normalize(y_true,axis=1)
b=tf.math.l2_normalize(y_pred,axis=1)

print(a)
print(b)
print(np.mean(a*b,axis=1)
print(-np.sum(np.mean(a*b,axis=1)))

#[[0. 1.][0.70710677 0.70710677]]
#[[0. 1.][0. 1.]]
#[0.5        0.35355338]
# -0.8535534
#
```

3. I am not sure but `np.linalg.norm()` seems to give the norm of a vector/matrix
   Where *tensorflow* gives you the same matrix normalized (along the axis you selected)

So instead of using `np.linalg.norm()` use *Tensorflow* function `tf.math.l2_normalized(myarray,axis=1)`

```
def cosine_sim(y_true,y_pred):
    norm_true=tf.math.l2_normalize(y_true,axis=1)
    norm_pred=tf.math.l2_normalize(y_pred,axis=1)

    loss =-np.sum(np.mean(norm_true*norm_pred,axis=1))
    return loss
```